# CoroutineScope lifecycle issue

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Currently I am leaking coroutines created by `GlobalScope.launch()` the `Job` of which is not being cancelled in some circumstances. I was wondering if I created a `CoroutineScope()` instead in my function and whether or not the scope in which a CoroutineScope() is created, once garbage collected, cancels the job associated with my custom scope?

e.g.

```
class MyActivity: Activity {

    fun myCustomCoroutineScopeScope() {
       job = CoroutineScope.launch {
           endlessFunctionCall()
       }
    }

    suspend fun endlessFunctionCall() {
        while (isActive) {
         // perform work
        }
    }

    // sometimes not invoked when application terminates
    fun cleanup() {
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the coroutine scope won't be garbage collected until the job finishes or is cancelled. But instead of doing that, there's `lifecycle.coroutineScope` that can be used in the activity instead, which will be cancelled on destroy.

Comment: @Nicolas thank you! It makes me think whether there are any real instances where you would ever want to create a Coroutine in an android context without using the `lifecycle.coroutineScope`. Unless i guess you wanted to run a coroutine in the background while  an activity was destroyed, assuming you were maintaining the job somewhere else?

Comment: I never needed to do it personally. Perhaps that can happen if you need it in your model layer since you don't have access to the fragment or activity there. But in general the methods there are `suspend`ing so there's no need for that, the coroutine context is passed implitcitly from the caller.

Comment: Maybe for saving a large file, where you don't want it cancelled if the user navigates away. But maybe in that case you should be using a foreground service so the OS doesn't shut you down unexpectedly.